# Llamar el valor de una variable de un archivo a otro

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Mi situación está en que tengo dos archivos PHP en el cual:

- `Archivo1.php` (formulario)
- `Archivo2.php` me genera un código consecutivo.

¿Cómo puedo obtener mi código generado en `archivo2.php` y mandarlo o solicitarlo a mi `archivo1.php` (formulario) en cual lo pretendo almacenar en un `input text`?

Agrego mi contenido para que vean lo que necesito realizar

Mi formulario principal se genera una solicitud.

[image: Formulario ingresa datos por medio de ajax]

mi botón agregar solicitud de tipo submit ejecuta la inserción desde AJAX. O habrá una manera de mostrar mi resultado en el input, así como se encuesta la pagina con el valor del folio.

[image: Código inserción ajax]

Una vez presionado mi botón se inserta los datos a a mi base de datos  y a su vez genera mi folio consecutivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen en el comentario donde dice aquí se genera el código, ese valor de la variable es la que requiero l lo quiero en un input text en mi formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el input text es el que se encuentra debajo de mi botón de agregar solicitud y en frente de tipo de descarga, esto apartado aparece una vez que se agrega el registro.

Espero haberme dado a entender

Comment: el consecutivo se realiza en base a la información del formulario o solo es un consecutivo que se genera solo?

Comment: Con un ajax y te traes el resultado en el onsuccess, o lo guardas en base de datos y consultas la base de datos, o lo tendrás en el archivo 2 y desde allí reenvías al archivo 1 enviando la variable por ejemplo en la URL para recogerla por get. Depende de la relación entre ambos archivos y la funcionalidad, como ya ha preguntado Andrés. Falta información.

Comment: @AngelMontesdeOca por favor, te pido prestar un poco de atención en las sugerencias de edición. Hay [casos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/51754) en los que estás eliminando tildes incorrectamente, o sugiriendo formato de código para lo que no es código. Recomendaría que revises [tus últimas sugerencias](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/36135/angel-montes-de-oca?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) rechazadas, junto a todas las que un revisor editó corrigiendo partes de tu edición.

Comment: No me termina de quedar clara cuál es la relación entre Archivo1.php y Archivo2.php, ¿incluyes uno en el otro? ¿Cuál es el target del formulario en Archivo1.php? ¿A que te refieres con "me genera un código consecutivo"?

Comment: Gracias a todos por responder, acabo de agregar contenido para que sea mas atendible.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes es mandar los datos por la url, aunque esto no es seguro si envias datos sensibles como contraseñas:

En `Archivo1.php` envias los datos:

En `Archivo2.php` recives los datos de un form y haces lo que tengas que hacer, para enviar los datos en un a `Archivo1.php` los tienes que hacer es desde `Archivo2.php` regirigir con parametros ejemplo

```
//Archivo2.php
<?php
    //hacer algo con los datos
    //devolver datos a Archivo1.php
    header("location: informacion=" + $informacion +"); //informacion lleva los datos que quieres devolver, puedes mandar varios parametros.
?>
```

**Ahora en `Archivo1.php`**

```
$valor = isset($_GET['informacion']) ? $_GET['informacion'] : ''; //si la variable get informacion existe tomas esa informacion y meterla a $valor si no dejarle un string vacio
<input type="text" name="informacion" id="informacion" value = "<?=$valor?>"> <!--<?=$valor?> es una manera corta de escribir <?php echo $valor?>-->
```